# Can not use google cloud print in nexus10 tablet - OS version 5.1.1

Tags: android, google-cloud-print

I have put some code for WiFi printing from nexus10 tablet to Epson Printer through Google Cloud Print - but, it does not move to the google cloud option

Android Version - 5.1.1

**PrintHelper Class**

```
public void testPrintHelper(Bitmap bmA) {

    PrintHelper printHelper = new PrintHelper(this);
    printHelper.setScaleMode(PrintHelper.SCALE_MODE_FIT);
    printHelper.setColorMode(PrintHelper.COLOR_MODE_MONOCHROME);
    printHelper.printBitmap("OrderName", bmA, new OnPrintFinishCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You forgot to include your code.

Comment: What's the problem/error? Specify your issue precisely.

Comment: should I use the Google Cloud Print from Android Lollipop or not..?